# How to like two columns in one SQL statement

Tags: sql

How to write this SQL?

```
Table A Column aa
-----
jack
jim
alan

Table B Column bb
-----
jacky
jimmy
william
```

The output is:

```
-----
jack jacky
jim jimmy
```

Because aa's value is bb's substring.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
Select aa, bb
from a, b
where a.aa like '%' + b.bb + '%'
   OR b.bb like '%' + a.aa + '%'
```

for mysql  you need use concat('%', field, '%')

for oracle you need use '||' insteaf of '+'

Answer (score 4):

You can construct a pattern from the substring:

```
select a.aa, b.bb
from TableA a
inner join TableB b on b.bb like '%' + a.aa + '%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like

```
DECLARE @TableA TABLE(
        AA VARCHAR(20)
)
INSERT INTO @TableA SELECT 'jack'
INSERT INTO @TableA SELECT 'jim'
INSERT INTO @TableA SELECT 'alan' 

DECLARE @TableB TABLE(
        BB VARCHAR(20)
)
INSERT INTO @TableB SELECT 'jacky'
INSERT INTO @TableB SELECT 'jimmy'
INSERT INTO @TableB SELECT 'william'

SELECT  *
FROM    @TableA A,
        @TableB B
WHERE   B.BB LIKE '%' + A.AA + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT
       a.aa, b.bb
FROM   
       a
JOIN   
       b ON b.bb like '%' + a.aa + '%'
```

But you have to be very carefully because you can find multiple rows returned for the same name.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
SELECT
       a.aa, b.bb
FROM   
       a
JOIN   
       b ON b.bb like '%' || a.aa || '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

To Improve Performance,
Use Virtual column (you can create index etc).

```
create table text2(
x number(10),
x1 as  ('%'||x||'%'))

insert into text2 (x) values ('100')
insert into text2 (x) values ('33')
commit

select * from text2

create table text1
( x number(10));

insert into text1 values (100 );
insert into text1 values (1001);
insert into text1 values (3300);

commit;

select text1.x, text2.x1 from text1 , text2 
where text1.x like text2.x1
```

X   X1
33  %33%
100 %100%

to know more about virtual column , 
http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle11g/oracle_11g_function_based_columns.htm

-Raj